# Strange results with BITXOR in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I get the following results with Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.6701.1011) 64-bit:

```
=BITXOR(10,1111)
```

produces:

```
1117
```

I expected `1101`.

However `=BITXOR(10,111)` produces `101` which is what I expected.

Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result, if 1111 and 10 are decimal. If u watch this binary, it looks like it should do:

```
  10 =        1010b
1111 = 10001010111b
----------XOR----------
       10001011101b = 1117
```

So you have to convert your numbers to decimals first.

Comment: Thanks `=DEC2BIN(BITXOR(BIN2DEC(10),BIN2DEC(1111)))` works as expected.